# RecyclerView inside RecyclerView scroll in same direction

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 2 recycler views, let's call then recycler1 and recycler2 (purple background). The squares with yellow background are elements of recycler2 which has an instance inside of each element of recycler1. What I'm trying to achieve is that it should scroll elements of recycler2 on purple area fling and recycler1 outside it. I made it with horizontal scroll (which is very easy) but can't do it vertically. I tried to set and reset nested scrolling and behaviour and whatever but can't make it work.

[image]

Below the code (a lot of it):

InnerItem Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_width="60dp"
         android:background="#38f"
         android:padding="4dp"
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:background="#ffff00"
    android:id="@+id/tag_text_view"
    android:text="Some Content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Nested recycler item

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="#cfcfcf"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_name_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:background="#1ad"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_name_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#d65"
            />
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/nested_recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="#659"
                >
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

InnerItem

```
package com.yrs.androidltx.features.adapterviews.nestedrecycler;
public class InnerItem {
    String tag;
    public InnerItem(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

InnerItem Adapter

```
package com.yrs.androidltx.features.adapterviews.nestedrecycler;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.yrs.androidltx.R;
import java.util.List;

public class InnerItemAdapter extends    RecyclerView.Adapter<InnerItemViewHolder> {
    List<InnerItem> innerItemList;

    public InnerItemAdapter(List<InnerItem> innerItemList) {
        this.innerItemList = innerItemList;
    }

    @Override
    public InnerItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.inner_item, parent, false);
        InnerItemViewHolder viewHolder = new InnerItemViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(InnerItemViewHolder holder, int position){
        holder.tagTextVIew.setText(innerItemList.get(position).tag);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return innerItemList.size();
    }
}
```

InnerItem ViewHolder

```
    package com.yrs.androidltx.features.adapterviews.nestedrecycler;

    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.yrs.androidltx.R;


    public class InnerItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tagTextVIew;

        public InnerItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tagTextVIew = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag_text_view);
        }
    }
```

Person

```
    package com.yrs.androidltx.features.adapterviews.nestedrecycler;


    public class Person {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;


        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }
```

Person ViewHolder

```
    package com.yrs.androidltx.features.adapterviews.nestedrecycler;

    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.yrs.androidltx.R;

    public class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //Keep package visibility
        TextView firstNameTextView;
        TextView lastNameTextView;
        RecyclerView nestedRecyclerView;

        public PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            firstNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_name_textView);
            lastNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_name_textView);
            nestedRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nested_recycler);
        }
    }
```

Person Adapter

```
    package com.yrs.androidltx.features.adapterviews.nestedrecycler;

    import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import com.yrs.androidltx.R;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;


    public class PersonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonViewHolder> {

        List<Person> personList;

        public PersonAdapter(List<Person> personList) {
            this.personList = personList;
        }

        @Override
        public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater
                    .from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.nested_recycler_item, parent, false);
            PersonViewHolder personViewHolder = new PersonViewHolder(view);
            return personViewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.firstNameTextView.setText(personList.get(position).getFirstName());
            holder.lastNameTextView.setText(personList.get(position).getLastName());
            holder.nestedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(holder.nestedRecyclerView.getContext(), 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false ));
            holder.nestedRecyclerView.setAdapter(new InnerItemAdapter(initTagList()));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return personList.size();
        }

        private List<InnerItem> initTagList() {
            List<InnerItem> tagList = new ArrayList<>();

            tagList.add(new InnerItem("android"));
            tagList.add(new InnerItem("iOS"));
            tagList.add(new InnerItem("windows"));
            tagList.add(new InnerItem("linux"));
            tagList.add(new InnerItem("NetBSD"));
            tagList.add(new InnerItem("NetWare"));

            //repeat few times...
            return  tagList;
        }
    }
```

Main activity

```
    package com.yrs.androidltx.features.adapterviews.nestedrecycler;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

    import com.yrs.androidltx.R;
    import com.yrs.androidltx.activities.base.BaseActivity;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class WithNestedRecyclerActivity extends BaseActivity {

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private PersonAdapter personAdapter;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_recycler);

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            personAdapter = new PersonAdapter(initDataSet());

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(personAdapter);

        }

        private List<Person> initDataSet() {
            List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

            personList.add(new Person("Ned","Flanders"));
            personList.add(new Person("Homer","Simpson"));
            personList.add(new Person("Bart","Simpson"));
            personList.add(new Person("Mr","Burns"));

            //... repeat few times

            return personList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your problem. Is each element in recyclerview2 a recycler view?

Comment: It's other way around, recyclerview2 is an element inside recyclerview1.

Comment: Basically recyclerview1 containes elements that contain inside 1 recyclerview2. If you have 10 items in recyclerview1 then you'll have 10 of recyclerview2.